# Do we need to use runserver command in production to start our django project?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, uwsgi, wsgi

Do we need to use runserver command in production to start our project? If yes, then how to do it, and If No then how does out project server starts?

Comment: Theres a big message in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver) - "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING"

Comment: You need to use something like `gunicorn` that creates django workers. Then use a server like `Nginx` as a reverse proxy to "serve" them. Here's a tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Currently I am using openlitespeed server, then do I still need to use Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way starting Django in production for now is using UWSGI (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (or an asynchronous version ASGI)
You need config like this:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:3300
chdir = /app/src
pythonpath=/app/src
wsgi-file = /app/src/django_app/wsgi.py
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_app.settings
module = django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()
max-requests = 1000
harakiri = 60
buffer-size = 65535
no-orphans = true
touch-reload = /var/run/uwsgi-touch-reload
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
master = 1
workers = 8
```

And then you start your application with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
uwsgi --ini /app/uwsgi.ini
```

And then your HTTP server, for example nginx, sends requests to uwsgi application. Nginx config my be like this:

```
upstream django {
    server django:3300;
}

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    default_type  text/html;
    uwsgi_pass django;
    uwsgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL 'https';
}
```

Comment: I am using openlitespeed server and wsgi.py file, will I need uwsgi file? Or wsgi file is enough?